# Why Browser Tabs Reload After Restoring Back From Multi-Tasking?

Tags: browser, restore, multitasking, bandwidth

When i have tabs opened no matter in which browser and restore back to that browser due to previous multi-tasking, i get all tabs reloading (or would it be more correct to say, loading again from scratch?).

I thought when multi-tasking, tabs are supposed to leave at state they previously were in. So when certain websites were already loaded, why would they reload again and consume bandwidth?

**UPDATE:** Here is my device's memory status *(sorry for bad quality but until Android implements screenshot feature in stock ROM or until i decide to ROOT, i will be capturing with another device's low quality camera)*:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Where are the rest of 499MB of memory? My device notifies me of low memory but what about the rest of 499MB? And did i mention that HTC Sense force closes **when i multi-task**?

Comment: After your update: The reason is same what I mentioned in my answer. If your calculation is unable to explain memory usage, there are memory leaks of app(s).

Comment: @SachinShekhar Then how do i find apps that leak?

Answer (score 3):

It happens when tab is unloaded from memory.

Your thinking for multitasking is right, but just for multitasking, Android can't let device crashing happen, for example (device hardware resources are limited). There are many things which should be given higher priority than a background app. When foreground app needs high amount of memory, background apps are unloaded fully or partially from memory. Technically, when free memory drops below certain level, attack on background apps is performed. In fact, foreground app can also be attacked when kernel runs out of memory.

When it comes to websites, web browsers often make request of removed things of website (which aren't available in disc cache). To re-construct a web page, its better to reload webpage.
You can check it with Dolphin Browser HD: Send it to background & disconnect from internet. Then, re-open it. Webpage will be reloaded, but using cache (mind it, there's no internet connection).